# Contenteditable regex whitespace not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am trying to validate if the contenteditiable value has only whitespace/blank space. In my example if the value have only whitespace/blank space it should not match according to my regex string, but it not working as intended. It keeps matching when I enter complete blank spaces.

***edit: the black space is where you can enter text.***

https://jsfiddle.net/j1kcer26/5/

JS

```
var checkTitle = function() {
  var titleinput = document.getElementById("artwork-title").innerHTML;
  var titleRegexp = new RegExp("^(?!\s*$).+"); //no blank spaces allowed
  if (!titleRegexp.test(titleinput)) {
    $('.start').removeClass('active-upload-btn');
    console.log('no match')

  } else if (titleRegexp.test(titleinput)) {
    $('.start').addClass('active-upload-btn');
    console.log('match')
  }
};

$('#artwork-title').on('keyup change input', function() {
  checkTitle();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="post-title-header">
  <span class="user-title-input title-contenteditable maxlength-contenteditable" placeholder="enter text here" contenteditable="true" name="artwork-title" id="artwork-title" autocomplete="off" type="text" spellcheck="false"> 
  </span>
</div>

<div class="start">
      turn red if match
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of what `innerHTML` is set to that's not matching as expected?

Comment: the black space is an input field, sorry I should have made it clear.

Comment: The innerHTML is full of &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; and other entities, not actual whitespaces.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the actual inner HTML, you'll see things like `<br>` elements or `&nbsp;` entities. Your regex doesn't look equipped to handle these.

You may want to consider using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML` if you just care about the text, not the HTML. Or alternatively, if you really want plain text, use a `<textarea/>` instead of a content-editable div, which is for rich-text-style editing that produces HTML.

**Edit**:

Your regex is not quite right either. Because you're using the `RegExp` constructor with `new RegExp("^(?!\s*$).+")`, the `\s` in your string literal is going to turn into a plain `s`; you have to use a `\\s` if you want the regex to have an actual `\s` in it. IMO, it's always better to use a regexp literal unless you're building one dynamically, like `/^(?!\s*$).+/`, or I find this to be a simpler alternative to tell you if a string is entirely whitespace: `/^\s+$/`.

Comment: I want to get the text only so I changed it to var titleinput = $('#artwork-title').text(); But I am still getting match value for empty spaces. New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tkvefqgr/1/